# redirect to specific tab after reload in laravel using bootstrap v4

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4, tabs

I have a page with 3tabs. I need to make the page to redirect to the same tab that came from before reload.I quess each tab shuold add a string to url for example #menu1 #menu2 but it doesnt
I'll share my codes. I am new in laravel and dont know how to handle it. please guid me to fix this.
I appreciate any help and suggestion.

```
    @extends('admin.main')
@section('title') {{ !empty($article) ? 'ویرایش اطلاعات فروشگاه ' : 'ثبت اطلاعات فروشگاه' }} @endsection
@section('content')
    <main class="app-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-left">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">پنل مدیریت</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item">{{ !empty($article) ? 'ویرایش اطلاعات فروشگاه ' : 'ثبت اطلاعات فروشگاه' }}</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <h3 class="tile-title">{{ !empty($article) ? 'ویرایش اطلاعات فروشگاه ' : 'ثبت اطلاعات فروشگاه' }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <hr/>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="shop-condition-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                               href="#shop-condition" role="tab" aria-controls="shop-condition" aria-selected="true">قوانین
                                خرید</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="order-submit-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#order-submit"
                               role="tab" aria-controls="order-submit" aria-selected="false">روش‌های ارسال</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="product-coupon-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                               href="#product-coupon" role="tab" aria-controls="product-coupon" aria-selected="false">تخفیف‌ها</a>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="shop-condition" role="tabpanel"
                             aria-labelledby="shop-condition-tab">
                            <div class="tile-body">
                                <form action="{{ route('updateProductCondition', 'shop') }}" method="POST"
                                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    @csrf
                                    {{  @method_field('PATCH') }}
                                    <hr class="colorize" style="width: 45%;margin-right: 0px;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <textarea
                                                    class="tinymce withImgUpload {{ $errors->has('spf_product_condition_description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                                    rows="12"
                                                    name="spf_product_condition_description">{!! old('spf_product_condition_description', $condition)!!}</textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <button class="btn btn-success storeAjax">ثبت</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="order-submit" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="order-submit-tab">
                            <div class="tile-body">
                                <form action="{{ route('storeProductSubmit') }}" method="POST"
                                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    @csrf
                                    <hr class="colorize" style="width: 45%;margin-right: 0px;">
                                    
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col">
                                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                            <label for="title" class="control-label">عنوان</label>
                                            <br>   
                                            <input type="text" id="title-shop" name="title" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col">
                                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                            <label for="price" class="control-label">هزینه</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" id="price_shop" name="price" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="form-group col">
                                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                            <label for="time_type">واحد زمان رسیدن</label>
                                            <select name="time_type" class="form-control" id="publish_status">
                                                <option value="null">انتخاب کنید</option>
                                                <option value="day">روز</option>
                                                <option value="hour" >ساعت</option>
                                                <option value="week">هفته</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group col">
                                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                            <label for="time" class="control-label">زمان رسیدن</label>
                                            <input type="number" min="0" id="delivery_time" name="time" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 10px">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <button class="btn btn-success storeAjax">ثبت</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </form>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-xs">
                                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>عنوان</th>
                                                    <th>هزینه</th>
                                                    <th>واحد زمان رسیدن</th>
                                                    <th>زمان رسیدن</th>
                                                    <th>اقدامات</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            @foreach($productSubmits as $productSubmit)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>{{ $productSubmit->title }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $productSubmit->price }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $productSubmit->time_type }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $productSubmit->time }}</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="d-flex">
                                                            <a href="{{ route('editProductSubmit', $productSubmit->id) }}" class="fa fa-pencil text-dark">ویرایش</a>
                                                            <form action="{{ route('deleteProductSubmit', $productSubmit->id) }}" method="POST">
                                                            @csrf
                                                            @method('DELETE')
                                                                <button type="submit" class="fa fa-times text-dark mr-2">حذف</button>
                                                            </form>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                                <td colspan="5" class="text-center">موردی برای نمایش وجود ندارد</td>
                                                
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="product-coupon" role="tabpanel"
                             aria-labelledby="product-coupon-tab">
                            <div class="tile-body">
                                <form action="{{ route('storeProductCoupon') }}" method="POST"
                                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    @csrf
                                    {{ !empty($article) ? @method_field('PATCH') : '' }}
                                    <hr class="colorize" style="width: 100%;margin-right: 0px;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                //
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <button class="btn btn-success storeAjax">ثبت</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
@endsection

@section('script')
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for doing that you need to save tab ID in cookies or browser storage. your using bootstrap 4 tab you can do that like bellow.via javascript

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
  let activeTab = $(event.target), // activated tab
      id = activeTab.attr('href'); // active tab href

     // set id in html5 localstorage for later usage      
     localStorage.setItem('activeTab', id);

});
```

now the ID of tab saved in user browser storage you can get back the id after page load.

```
window.onload = function() {
  let tabID = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
  $(tabID).tab('show');
};
```

for more info read bootstrap 4 tab DOC. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript